# cmake-Unable to find the requested Boost libraries

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cmake, cgal, cmake-gui

I want to use CGAL libraries , I'm using :
CGAL 4.10 ,Microsoft visual studio 2013 , CMake 3.9.3 , boost 1.65, QT creator 4.3.1

while Configuring CGAL using Cmake , it is showing the following errors:

```
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - not found
Found Threads: TRUE  
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1902 (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupBoost.cmake:21 (find_package)
cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupDependencies.cmake:85 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:681 (include)


Boost include:     Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
Boost libraries:   
Boost definitions: 
USING BOOST_VERSION = '..'
== Detect external libraries (DONE) ==

== Write compiler_config.h ==
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_DENORMALS_COMPILE_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_FPU_ROUNDING_MODE_UNWINDING_VC_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_IEEE_754_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_ISTREAM_INT_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_5 - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_6 - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_7 - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_8 - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NESTED_CLASS_FRIEND_DECLARATION_BUG - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_LIMITS - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_NEXTAFTER - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_STL - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NUMERIC_LIMITS_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_OUTOFLINE_MEMBER_DEFINITION_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_TEMPLATE_IN_DEFAULT_PARAMETER_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_TYPENAME_BEFORE_DEFAULT_ARGUMENT_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_USING_BASE_MEMBER_BUG_2 - Success
== Write compiler_config.h (DONE) ==


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they     are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the  CMake files:
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
used as include directory in directory C:/dev/CGAL-4.10/src/CGAL
used as include directory in directory C:/dev/CGAL-4.10/src/CGAL
used as include directory in directory C:/dev/CGAL-4.10/src/CGAL_Core
used as include directory in directory C:/dev/CGAL-4.10/src/CGAL_Core
used as include directory in directory C:/dev/CGAL-4.10/src/CGAL_ImageIO
used as include directory in directory C:/dev/CGAL-4.10/src/CGAL_ImageIO
```

I added Boost_INCLUDE_DIR,BOOST_ROOT manually to environment vairables

Boost_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\dev\boost_1_65_0;BOOST_ROOT=C:\dev\boost_1_65_0

I tried many versions of boost ,cmake and cgal with visual sutudio 2015 , 2013 and non of the was working

I appreciate any help.thank you

Comment: The error message tells you to set `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR`, not `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR`

Comment: I tried your solution, it shows the same error:
Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing Boost's headers.

Comment: What is the content of `C:\dev\boost_1_65_0`?

Comment: Boost package (boost , doc,libs,status,tools ,more)folders

Comment: I recommend you to install boost so that you have only `<prefix>/include` and `<prefix>/lib`. This makes it easier for CMake to find it, and then you only need to set `BOOST_ROOT`.

Comment: If you just set BOOST_ROOT it should find everything, provided that you have built any libraries that need building (Boost.Test, etc.) in your BOOST_ROOT.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cygwin, you can use cmake-gui and use the interface to fill your path, this limits the risk of typos and it is more obvious to find the missing fields.
Another option is to edit hte CMakeCache.txt in your build directory to give the paths, so you don't have to declare the variables as environment variables.